# Using multidymentional array in c store a line from the user and return the words in the line in decending order according to the word length

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, computer-science, c-strings

Write a program which read a line from user until user press enter key ('\n'). Store all the words of a line
into multidimensional dynamic array. Then pass this array to a function SortString(), which will sort all the
words by word length i.e. longest word will be placed at a first index, then second longest word will be
placed at a second index and so on. Finally return the sorted list of words back to main function, where
all the words will be printed onto the screen as one word per line. Assume that the line contains all unique
words.

I have written some code here but I am having problems with how to sort the lengths of the words in the line and print them in descending order.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
main(){
    char string[50];
    int i, l;
    char *ptr, *p;
    printf("Enter the string: ");
    gets(string);
    l=strlen(string);
    ptr=(char*)malloc((l+1)*sizeof(char));
    p=ptr;
    if(ptr==NULL){
        printf("\n Enter out of memory");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i=0;i<l;i++){
        *ptr=string[i];
        ptr++;
    }
    *ptr='\0';  
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you would show your sorting function aka "sortString()" too

Comment: Why are you using malloc if your string is limited to 50 bytes length?

Comment: Matheus what should I do then and what if the user enters a huge line.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that has functions that can get the number of words in a \0 terminated string and put them into an array of strings. These functions use strtok which can be used to split a string by a delimiter (in our case ' ' since we want to separate the string by words).

A comparing function "compare" is used with the sort function to sort the strings in words by length. In main the newly sorted strings are printed.

After everything is done in main, the delete words function frees up memory.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

bool isWhiteSpace(char c) {
    return c == ' ' || c == '\t' || c == '\n';
}

int getWordCount(char* string) {
    bool insideWord = false;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 0;

    while (string[i] != '\0') {
        if (!insideWord) {
            if (!isWhiteSpace(string[i])) {
                insideWord = true;
                count++;
            }
        }
        else {
            if (isWhiteSpace(string[i])) {
                insideWord = false;
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    return count;
}

char** getWords(char* inputString, int wordCount) {
    char** newArray = (char**)malloc(wordCount * sizeof(char*));

    char* word = strtok(inputString, " ");
    int i = 0;
    while (word != NULL) {
        newArray[i] = (char*)malloc((strlen(word) + 1) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(newArray[i], word);
        word = strtok(NULL, " ");
        i++;
    }

    return newArray;
}

int compare(const void* s1, const void* s2) {
    return strlen(*(char**)s1) - strlen(*(char**)s2);
}

void deleteWords(char** words, int wordCount) {
    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        free(words[i]);
    }
    free(words);
}

int main() {
    printf("Enter a string: ");
    char* inputString = NULL;
    size_t buffersize = 0;
    ssize_t inputLength = 0;
    
    // getline doesn't add a \0.
    inputLength = getline(&inputString, &buffersize, stdin);
    // replace \n with \0
    inputString[inputLength - 1] = '\0';

    int wordCount = getWordCount(inputString);
    printf("wc: %d\n", wordCount);
    char** words = getWords(inputString, wordCount);

    // Sort the words on length.
    qsort(words, (size_t)wordCount, sizeof(char*), compare);

    for (int i = 0; i < wordCount; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    // Free up the memory.
    deleteWords(words, wordCount);

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Carl I can't see your getline() function.

Comment: getline comesfrom stdlib.h It does what you were trying to do with gets. gets has been deemed insecure however and removed from the STL so and replaced with getline and fgets